# Amazon Kinesis, Lambda and DLQ - how to properly get payload contents from the DLQ in a large traffic scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

Kinesis DLQ does not contain the payload, only the metadata. You're supposed to read the payload [like in this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153508/kinesis-with-sqs-dlq-missing-event-data) by calling `GetRecords`.

My setup is as follows:

```
Apps -->  Kinesis Data Stream ---> Kinesis Firehose ---> S3 [all events]
            |                 ---> Processing Lambda ---> <external service> 
            |                          |
            |                          |
       DLQ Lambda <-------------------- DLQ
            | 
             ---> S3 [failed events]
```

Basically:

- I'm getting 1000s of messages per second onto Kinesis Data Stream
- the stream is consumed by two consumers - Kinesis Firehose and Processing Lambda (with EFO)
- Processing Lambda has a DLQ set up in case the processing fails (after some retries, partial failures and bisect)
- since DLQ does not contain the payload, that DLQ is consumed by a "DLQ Lambda" to read the payload and save it to S3

Unfortunately, `GetRecords` is limited to 5 calls per second per Shard. You also cannot set up Kinesis Firehose to use EFO, **which in turn means that Firehose and DLQ Lambda share the capacity**.

Now, when there's a large spike in failures (multiple shards, large parallelization factor and a downtime of the external service), I feel like DLQ might get overflown with failed messages metadata. Then, not only `GetRecords` for each shard might get throttled, it might affect Firehose as well (and I absolutely need Firehose to work at all times!).

On the other hand, if I tweak the DLQ Lambda settings to ensure that it only gets invoked 2-3 times per second (for example by setting SQS concurrency and making Lambda artificially never take less than 300ms), I might not have enough time to consume all messages on the DLQ before they expire on Kinesis Data Stream. **Essentially: more messages will come onto the DLQ than I'm able to process.**

Of course it all varies on the load of the system, bisect settings, parallelization factor, batch size, retry count and so on, but I feel like this is a hard problem.

**Question:** What would you suggest? Is there a standard guideline on how to handle the failed DLQ messages from Kinesis "at scale"? I don't see a simple way to ensure that the DLQ Lambda adheres to the Shard `GetRecords` limits.

Side note - this gets even worse if I add more consumers (for now there are just two, but Flink is planned soon) and each of these consumers has its own DLQ. I'll ignore that for now.

Answer (score 1):

While `GetRecords` API only supports 5 TPS per shard, it can actually return up to 10,000 records or up to 10MB ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)).

So as long as your DLQ lambda batches failed records into batches of 10,000 I  think it should have sufficient capacity to read them all, because each shard can at most get 1000 records per seconds (or 1MB/sec) written, so you should not exceed 10,000 records per second over extended period of time.

As for sharing capacity, each shard in Kinesis can support 2 readers at max capacity (up to 1 MB/sec or 1,000 records/sec write throughput or up to 2 MB/sec or 2,000 records/sec read throughput), so as long as you don't have more than 2, this should be fine. If you keep adding more DLQs, then you can try reusing the same DLQ read lambda to read from multiple DLQs so that you only have 1 DLQ consumer.

Comment: This would work if the DLQ messages contained small batches of data (start/end sequence numbers). Unfortunately, we use bisect on failure + partial failures, so the DLQ Lambda would need to somehow merge adjacent sequence numbers, which is probably not easy.

Regarding "a shared" DLQ - that's a nice idea, but this once again limits the throughput of "reading the Kinesis messages" of the system. If all consumers have suddenly start failing, then the DLQ is overflown with messages and might not have enough time to pull them from the stream.